# The Image of Diagonal Morphism $\Delta(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes, fibre-product

I'm trying to understand the fact from Algebraic Geometry which is just assumed to be true everywhere I see it. The fact is that:

Let $X$ be a scheme and $X \to S$ a morphism. Denote by $\Delta_{X/S} : X \to X \times_S X$
the diagonal morphism. Let $Z = \{y \in X \times_S X : p_1(y) \equiv p_2(y)\}$. Where $p_1,p_2: X \times_S X\to X$ projections and

if  we have $f, g : K \to X$ be morphisms of schemes, let $x \in K$, and let $i_x : \operatorname{Spec} (\kappa(x)) \to K$
denote the associated canonical morphism. Then we say $f(x) \equiv g(x)$ if $f \circ i_x = g \circ i_x$. Equivalently: $f(x) = g(x)$ and the maps on residue fields $\kappa(f(x)) \to \kappa(x)$ induced by $f^{\#}_x$, $g^{\#}_x$
are equal.

Show that $Z = \Delta_{X/S}(X)$

I spent a lot of time trying to understand it myself, but I think I'm missing important in my understanding of Schemes. I will appreciate any help!

Comment: The third paragraph underlines that  $p_1(x)=p_2(x)$ is not enough and it should also induce equal maps on residue fields.

Comment: I think the inclusion $\Delta(X)\subset Z$ follows directly from the fact that $p_{1}\circ \Delta = p_{2}\circ \Delta$. For the condition that the maps on residue fields are equal you just have to look at the equality as being equal as morphisms. That is $(p_{1}\circ\Delta)^{\#} = (p_{2}\circ\Delta)^{\#}$. The other inclusion might be a bit trickier, and I hope that someone else knows the argument for this.

Comment: I see, thank you!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, $ \Delta(X) \subset Z $ is obvious.

It is enough to prove the other direction in the case that $ S = \operatorname{Spec} B $ and $ X = \operatorname{Spec} A $ are affine. Then $ X \times_S X = \operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes_B A) $ and let $ y \in Z $ correspond to the prime ideal $ P $ of $ A \otimes_B A $. Let $ i_1, i_2 : A \rightarrow A \otimes_B A $ be the maps $ i_1(a) = a \otimes 1 $, $ i_2(a) = 1 \otimes a $ and $ m : A \otimes_B A \rightarrow A $ the multiplication. Then the condition on $ y $ translates to: $ i_1^{-1}(P) = i_2^{-1}(P) = Q $ for a prime $ Q $ of $ A $ and the induced maps $ i_1^{\#}, i_2^{\#} : k(Q) \rightarrow k(P) $ are equal. In particular, evaluating at $ a \in A $, this implies that $ a \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes a \in P $ for all $ a \in A $.

Of course, the candidate element $ x \in X = \operatorname{Spec} A $ is the prime $ Q $ and the goal is to show that $ m^{-1}(Q) = P $. The following computation makes this clear: $$ a \otimes a' \pmod P = (a \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes a)(1 \otimes a') + 1 \otimes aa' \pmod P = 1 \otimes aa' \mod P $$ So if $ \gamma = \sum a \otimes a' $, then $ \gamma \pmod P = \beta \pmod P $ where $ \beta = \sum 1 \otimes aa' = 1 \otimes \sum aa' = 1 \otimes m(\gamma) $. Therefore $ \gamma \in P $ iff $ \beta \in P $ and from the fact that $ i_2^{-1}(P) =  Q $, $ \beta \in P $ iff $ m(\gamma) \in Q $. This proves the assertion $ m^{-1}(Q) = P $ and hence $ y $ is the image of $ x = Q $ under $ \Delta $.

In the general case, as noted by KReiser in the comments, let $ W $ and $ U $ be open neighborhoods of $ x $ and $ s $ respectively. Then $ W \times_U W $ is an open neighborhood of $ y $ in the fiber product (This is because the maps $ \operatorname{Spec} k(y) \rightarrow X \times_S X \xrightarrow{p_i} W $ induce a map $ \operatorname{Spec} k(y) \rightarrow W \times_U W $).

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: May you remind me, why we can reduce the proof to the case when S and X are affine?

Comment: @Rainbow57 Suppose $y\in X\times_S X$ so that $p_1(y)=p_2(y)=x$, and $f(x)=s\in S$. Then we can pick an affine open neighborhood $U$ of $s\in S$, and then pick an affine open neighborhood $W$ of $x\in X$ entirely contained inside $f^{-1}(U)$. Now $W\times_U W$ is an affine open neighborhood of $y$, and the projection maps $W\times_U W\to W$ and the maps $W\to U$ are just restrictions of the original maps $X\times_S X\to X$ and $X\to S$, so they haven't changed any of the data one might use to calculate whether $p_1(y)\equiv p_2(y)$ or not.

Comment: @Rainbow57 yeah, that's a good question, I admit I wasn't thinking about it clearly while writing the answer. The problem is to show that $ y $ is covered by some open set of the form $ W \times_U W $ like in KReiser's comment but I don't see immediately why the one in their comment covers $ y $.

Comment: So you might want to un-accept my answer for the time being.

Comment: @Ominusone $p_1(y)=p_2(y)=x\in W$, so the map $\{y\}\to W$ induces a map from $\{y\}$ to $W\times_U W$ which agrees with the inclusion map $\{y\}\to X\times_S X$, so $y\in W\times_U W$. Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: @KReiser, it does, thanks. That's the perfect way to see it. Do you want to add this as an answer for the OP?

Comment: @Ominusone I'd prefer not to. How about you add it to your answer? If you're worried about attribution, saying "as noted in the comments by KReiser" would be enough.

Comment: One way to note that $y\in W\times_U W$ is by observing that $W\times_U W=p_1^{-1}(W)\cap p_2^{-1}(W)$.